# Flex: How do you prevent the user from interacting with the area behind a pop-up?

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, mobile, popup

I want to prevent the user from clicking buttons that are behind a pop-up. How would I do this?

This is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" backgroundAlpha="0"     contentBackgroundAlpha="0" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:scripts="scripts.*">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function close_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.close();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Panel title="Optional Notes for Report" backgroundAlpha=".6" backgroundColor="#120242" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:HGroup height="100" width="100%">
    <s:TextArea id="notesTextArea" width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="14" styleName="labelWhite2" opaqueBackground="#200772" />
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:Image click="close_clickHandler(event)" fillMode="scale" scaleMode="letterbox" width="30%" 
                 smooth="false" smoothingQuality="high" source="@Embed('/assets/images/ok_button.png')"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Panel>
</s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the popup, make sure it is modal:

It is a property on both the [createPopUp()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#createPopUp%28%29) and [addPopUp()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#addPopUp%28%29) methods of the [PopUpManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html)

Comment: Could you please explain how using those methods would prevent the user from interacting with the area behind it? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Set the modal property to true when creating and displaying the popup.  Perhaps you should provide code to show how you display the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the modal property when you call the `open()` method

```
var popup:MyPopUp = new MyPopUp();
popup.open(this,true);
```